# How does Angular 2/4 determine which styles to place inline prior/post an animation?

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, angular-animations

I have the following trigger in an Angular 4 component animation array:

```
trigger('collection', [
  state('0', style({
    'background-color': 'black',
    '-webkit-box-flex': '0',
    '-ms-flex': '0 0 0px',
    flex: '0 0 0',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    'min-width': '0px',
  })),
  state('1', style({
    'background-color': 'blue',        
    '-webkit-box-flex': '1',
    '-ms-flex': '1 1 0px',
    flex: '1 1 0',
    'min-width': '450px',
  })),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('300ms ease-in')),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('300ms ease-out'))
]),
```

The styles that are added inline to the element per browser are as follows:

**State 0**

*IE 11 =>* overflow: hidden; min-width: 0px; background-color: black;

*Chrome =>* background-color: black; -webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 0px; overflow: hidden; min-width: 0px;

*Edge =>* flex:0 0 0px; overflow: hidden; min-width: 0px; background-color: black;

**State 1**

*IE 11 =>* min-width: 450px; background-color: blue;

*Chrome =>* background-color: blue; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0px; min-width: 450px;

*Edge =>* flex:1 1 0px; min-width: 450px; background-color: blue;

I ask this because, as you can probably tell, I am missing critical styles in IE, thus breaking the layout.

Edit 1) Just as an update, I never figured out exactly how the algorithm chooses which styles to place inline, but by finagling the css in the trigger state, I was able to solve my specific problem. Blatant luck helps sometimes I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve from the code,
But your question:

> How does Angular 2/4 determine which styles to place inline prior/post an animation?

Please read about **encapsulation** properties, i.e. **ViewEncapsulation**,
by default angular adds **Shadow-Dom** property to elements in components which makes two same elements in different components differentiate with each other,
If you want to determine why your styles are not working in **IE/edge**, You should probably add this to your component configuration,

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

This will tell Angular that **Please do not add your logic to keep the styles isolated inside the component**
Or you can also add **Native** property to let angular check that if the browser supports **shadow-dom** property then use **ViewEncapsulation** otherwise not,

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

By default it is set to **Emulated**, This is the reason angular does not allow the styles defined for a component to reflect outside the scope of the component.
Even if you give a generic styles to elements like

```
p {color: blue }
```

Angular will not allow it to modify elements present outside the component.

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
```

That is the reason the styles are not shown in IE/Edge, as they might not support **shadow-dom** property. You can set this property to **Native** to see the effect.

Hope this helps !
Thank You.

Comment: This is good information, but I don't believe this is related to encapsulation.  Edge, FF, and Chrome actually demonstrate correct functionality. IE is missing styles inline, which I suspect is causing problems. However, I don't know why IE is missing those styles, because I don't understand how the animation package decides what styles to insert inline. In the latest version of Angular (5), it actually threw errors for `'-webkit-box-flex': '1'` and `'-ms-flex': '1 1 0px'` in IE 11 (only IE 11 if I remember correctly), so I had to remove them altogether.

Comment: Hi @jpetitte,
My sincerest apologies i couldn't resolve your problem,
Please let me know when you find a solution by answering your own question unless correctly answered by experts !
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
flex: '0 0 0',
```

this should be

```
flex: '0 0 0px',
```

without px this style just got ignore

Comment: Hi Ravin. The style "-ms-flex: 1 1 0px" came directly from autoprefixer (though it looks like this has changed in a recent update). 'flex: 0 0 0px' is what was inserted into document by Angular, so I have no control over that. I just copy/pasted the output by Angular.

Comment: @jpetitte in your code example you mention flex:0 0 0. is that format you have in your source code, or you have as flex: 0 0 0px

Comment: I have flex: 0 0 0 in my source, which is another example of the lack of understanding regarding this system. That value is being translated (as far as I can tell) to 0 0 0px.